# Limit of sequence of sum of sinuses: $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}{(\sin(1+x) - \sin(x))}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How to find the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}{(\sin(1+x) - \sin(x))}$?

I don't even know how to begin.

Comment: Hint: this limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

$\sin (1+x)-\sin x = 2 \cos ( x+{1 \over 2}) \sin {1 \over 2}$.

Since $\sin {1 \over 2} \neq 0$, we see that $x \mapsto \sin (1+x)-\sin x$ takes the values $\pm 2  \sin {1 \over 2}$ infinitely often, hence no limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\sin(1+x) = \sin(1)\cos(x) + \sin(x)\cos(1)$

$\sin(1+x) - \sin(x) = \sin(1)\cos(x) + \sin(x)(\cos(1) - 1)$

this has the form: $a\sin(x) + b\cos(x)$

Conclude

Answer (score 1):

As Simon points out, the function does not have a limit as x approaches infinity.

Use the definition of a limit to show that this is the case (show that you cannot get as close as you want to a limit by making x larger).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if we define $f(x)=\sin(1+x)-\sin(x)$ we have that $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$, since its components are periodic. In particular, this means that if we were to show the existence of a limit $L$, we would have, for all $\varepsilon>0$ and some $N$:
$$\forall x>N[|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon]$$
but, this would mean that, for such $x$, so must $|f(x-2\pi n)-L|<\varepsilon$ for integer $n$ - and we quickly realize that *any* $x$ can be of this form, so we actually would need, for the limit to exist, to have:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\forall x[|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon]$$
or, equivalently, that $f(x)=L$ - that $f$ must be a constant function. To be precise this proves that any periodic function, with a limit as $x$ goes to infinity must be constant.

The given $f$ is not constant (for instance, $f(0)\neq f(\pi)$). Therefore that limit cannot converge, as $f$ will continually oscillate.

Answer (score 1):

No calculations are needed for this problem.

The sum of sinusoids of equal frequency is always a sinusoid (of that frequency).

The sum is obviously not a constant.

Nonconstant sinusoids don't have a limit.

So the limit doesn't exist.